# How can I check for a contour containing another contour using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing

Let's say I have the following image and I'm looking to analyse it with OpenCV in Python with Numpy:

[image: Checker board with dots]

I mark all the white blocks as contours. I also mark contours around the red and green dots.

**How do I check which dot is in which white block?**

Here's what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('crapypimg.bmp')
gray = cv2.imread('crapypimg.bmp',0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    print len(approx)
    if len(approx)==4:
        print "square"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),2)
    elif len(approx) == 9:
        print "half-circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(255,255,0),3)
    elif len(approx) > 15:
        print "circle"
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,255),3)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Improved grammar, formatting and moved the image inline

Comment: 1) find white connected components (your white blocks), 2) Create a new all zeros label image 3) set in the label image a different integer value (label) for points that belongs to the same white CC (you can easily do this with `setTo` and the mask of the white CC)  4) find the centroid for each green and red CC 5) Check the value in the label image for the centroid position. The integer value is the label of the white  box.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the shapes are not overlapping, it is enough to check one point against a contour.

You can use `cv2.pointPolygonTest` for this.

A tutorial is available [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('OFLCp.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]  # ensure binary
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

hierarchy is the answer to your question.If you will check hierarchy, it will look like this:

```
array([[[-1, -1,  1, -1],
        [ 3, -1,  2,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1,  1],
        [ 4,  1, -1,  0],
        [ 6,  3,  5,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1,  4],
        [ 7,  4, -1,  0],
        [ 9,  6,  8,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1,  7],
        [10,  7, -1,  0],
        [12,  9, 11,  0],
        [-1, -1, -1, 10],
        [-1, 10, -1,  0]]], dtype=int32)
```

where each row contains hierarchy information of the contour at that index.

*row = [next_contour_index, previous_contour_index, first_child_contour_index, parent_contour_index]*

so, 0 here is index of outermost square.
contour at index 2 (circle) has parent as 1 (square). Plotting one pair of child(red), parent (yellow).
[image]